Will my site be penalized in search engines for using data from a public API?
I am developing a website that utilizes the CoinGecko API to display cryptocurrency coin prices. I would like to understand the potential pitfalls or common issues I should be aware of as I proceed.
The URLs on both pages are somewhat similar:

URL on CoinGecko (site with API): /en/coins/bitcoin
URL on my site: /coin/bitcoin

My concerns are:

Will I be penalized by Google Search for using similar URLs?
Is there a risk of penalization for using CoinGecko's data on my website?


@MaximillianLaumeister i read guideline
Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com.
i believe this is right place for this question. and not stack overflow as i asking for seo advise and not prgramming advise

Got it, and thank you for your edit. I made another edit to further clarify that this is about SEO.

You won't be penalized for using similar URL's.   For a start Google has no problem rating and indexing Wordpress sites, and an aweful lot of them will have similar paths like /contact; /about-us; /home etc.  If other then the crypto prices your site has fairly unique content I doubt Google will penalize you for content because of the format of your site.
If you are using an API to pull in articles for Google for SEO purposes, that is a different story, and I expect if your sites/pages authority is low compared to other sites syndicating the same data it could hurt.

I am mainly getting market stats and showing those on my pages,
basically a lot of financial numbers like prices, market Capitalization, price changes. same figures are available on coingecko as well.
i am avoiding any long form content from coingecko, like coin descriptions, which are essentially few paragraphs about coins.
